# Access user data bag from scorable without IDialogContext

Tags: c#, botframework

Dialogs have the `IDialogContext` object to aaccess data bags.

Example:

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
```

How to access `context.UserDataBag` from scorable class global handler? 
It doesn't contain `IDialogContext` but I need user data from `botDataBag` in `scorable` class.

Comment: Can you add an example of the Scorable you would like to use?

Answer (score 2):

The usual way of doing this is using `IBotData` in your scorable.

You need to modify the constructor of your `IScorable` so it receives an `IBotData`, save it in a local variable, and use it later.

```
private readonly IBotData botData;

public ExtractCodeScorable(IBotToUser botToUser, IBotData botData) 
{ 
    this.botData = botData
}
```

Then you can use it as:

`this.botData.PrivateConversationData.SetValue(key, element.Value);` (or any of the other databags)

You can check the [demo-CardAttachments](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/demo-CardsAttachments/public-TestBot) sample as it heavily uses scorables and saves data in the data bags.

Comment: Was this useful?

Answer (score 1):

You can access `BotState` from the `Activity` object.
here is an example of a `Scorable` implementing `ScorableBase` and accessing `UserData`

```
public class CancelScorable : ScorableBase<IActivity, string, double>
{
    private readonly IDialogTask task;

    public CancelScorable(IDialogTask task)
    {
        SetField.NotNull(out this.task, nameof(task), task);
    }

    protected override async Task<string> PrepareAsync(IActivity activity, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // Accessing info, for example here UserData:
        var userData = await activity.GetStateClient().BotState.GetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id);

        // ... add your treatment

        return null;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: note: .GetStateClient() uses the default state client.  If using Bot Builder SDK Azure Extensions or a custom IBotDataStore (as recommended), the default state client will be interacting with a different store.