# Get the current Dialog on the DialogStack

Tags: c#, botframework

Is there a way to access the topmost/current `Dialog` on the `DialogStack` from a `Scorable`? This would be necessary to handle a help request in regard to context.

I can easily gain access to the stack itself by just passing it as a parameter, but as far as I can tell I can only start/end dialogs and access the delegates for resuming after the current dialogs.

Comment: Can you explain your use case more?  From your question, it seems you could use one of the databags in `context` to store what it is you need to provide the proper context.

Comment: I have a `Scorable` based on LUIS to save me training every dialog model for help requests etc. However the actual help text is saved in the dialog that is currently active, so I kind of need access to this current dialog. 
I haven't really looked into these databags yet, but I am not sure if that will be the solution, since there is other information, like an overview of the progress in the current dialog, that will be also needed in the `Scorable`, but obviously can't be saved statically (might be possible with databags, have to look into that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I could not find an answer that matches exactly my question, JasonSowers comment hinted into the right direction to solve the actual problem.
As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561504) you can save the data in the data bag instead of accessing the dialog.

To the actual question: my guess is that this is not accessible from this point. Please correct me if I am wrong and I will update this answer.